# TypeError: input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python

I got the following error: `TypeError: input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'` when trying to read from stdin in python using `fileinput.input()`, but the documentation says file input should be used like that.

I'm using python 3.9

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(encoding="utf-8"):
    process(line)
```

Comment: Your code probably needs to be fixed, but without seeing what that code is, what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: My bad, it was the first example from the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.9, `fileinput.input()` does not take an `encoding` argument (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/fileinput.html)). That argument was introduced in Python 3.10:

> Changed in version 3.10: The keyword-only parameter encoding and errors are added.